# Conditional formatting if cell contains time format hh:mm

Tags: regex, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have tried: `=$H4="8:15-9:00"` but failed.

What I want is to color a row if a certain cell contains i.e 8:15-9:00 or 12:00-12:25 or the like.

I have searched almost all Google's suggestions and stack overflow but I can't seem to get it right. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to apply it on range **A1:Z**:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A1), "\d+:\d+")
```

Comment: for full row use: `=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT($A1), "\d+:\d+")`

Comment: Perfect. Works.

Comment: If there are more than cell containing "\d+:\d+" how can I then expand your example? =REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT($A1:$H20), "\d+:\d+")?

Comment: I don't know if this the right way but appereantly this works for me: =REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT({$A1:$A40}), "\d+:\d+") applied to A1:Z.